# Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro 2013 is running slow

Tags: hdmi, macbook-pro, chromecast

I mainly use my old MacBook Pro 2012 retina to do Zoom sessions.
When I was running Big Sur I had lots of trouble running Zoom.
Sometimes it would seem to hang other times it was choppy.
Since I installed Ubuntu it seems to be running better.

But when running from Macosx I could install a cable from the Thunderbolt port to HDMI on my TV and see the screen.
When running Ubuntu, I see the desktop screen but not the desktop icons or the zoom screen.
Also, with that cable plugged into the Thunderbolt port to HDMI, it kills the cursor.
I have to take it out to get the cursor back.

So I would like to see if there is any way to solve these problems or to cast my MacBook Pro screen on my new **Samsung Q60C TV**.
If someone has faced these problems and has solved them, any help would be appreciated.

**System details:**

- Device: Macbook Pro 11.1
- Memory: 8GB
- Processor: Intet Core i7-4558u
- OS: UBUNTU 22.04.3 LTS
- Gnome version: 42.9
- Windowing System: Wayland

Comment: I am  really new to UBUNTU so bear with me I am more a mac person now. But Here is the information on my UBUNTU system. Hardware is Macbook pro 11.1, Memory 8GB, Processor Intet Core i7-4558u, OS UBUNTU 22.04.3 LTS 64 bit Gnome version 42.9  Windowing system Wayland. I hope that helps.